# I need a substitute for the vw and vh on the css file (edited)

Tags: html, css

So I was learning how to make a shoe website, but the content of the website keeps overflowing and doesn't fit my whole screen. I think the main reason is because I added `vw` and `vh` for the width and height respectively. I believe I need to replace it, but I'm not sure with what. (edit: i looked at the css file in deeper details and it's not just the vw and vh codes, it's more than that)

Here's the code:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap");
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #cb021c;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  transition: background 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.hamburger {
  position: fixed;
  top: 2rem;
  left: 2rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.phone {
  position: fixed;
  top: 2rem;
  right: 2rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.logo {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  margin: 2rem 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.logo i {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.logo h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
}

.logo p {
  color: #1f1f1f;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}

.carousel-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 60vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin-top: 10rem;
}

.carousel {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.slide {
  width: 100vw;
  text-align: center;
}

.slide img {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}

.slide h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 4rem;
  margin-top: -2rem;
}

.slide a {
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.arrow {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 5rem;
  color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.left-arrow {
  left: 2rem;
}

.right-arrow {
  right: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
    initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Footwear</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="#" class="hamburger">
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  </a>

  <a href="#" class="phone"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i></a>

  <div class="logo">
    <i class="fas fa-shoe-prints"></i>
    <h2>Shoe are us</h2>
    <p>Find the right fit for you</p>
  </div>

  <div class="carousel-container">
    <div class="carousel" id="carousel">
      <div class="slide" data-bg="cb021c">
        <img src="Images/shoe1.jpg" alt="shoe1" />
        <h1>Performance</h1>
        <a href="#">Learn More</a>
      </div>
      <div class="slide" data-bg="B3E140">
        <img src="Images/shoe2.jpg" alt="shoe2" />
        <h1>Design</h1>
        <a href="#">Learn More</a>
      </div>
      <div class="slide" data-bg="EEEFF1">
        <img src="Images/shoe3.jpg" alt="shoe3" />
        <h1>Comodity</h1>
        <a href="#">Learn More</a>
      </div>
      <div class="slide" data-bg="C6C5C1">
        <img src="Images/shoe4.jpg" alt="shoe4" />
        <h1>Lightness</h1>
        <a href="#">Learn More</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button id="left" class="left-arrow arrow">
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
    </button>
    <button id="right" class="right-arrow arrow">
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
    </button>

    <div class="progress"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean when you say "overflowing"? Everything seems to fit fine up until about small mobile devices viewport size where things feel a little tight but you can always adjust that with a media query or use viewport units to size things based on viewer width as needed.

Comment: Well, basically, the website on my monitor is too zoomed in and the h1's (like: perfomance) and the text (learn more) below the shoes jpgs aren't visible unless i zoom it out. (also, i guess i used the word "overflow" in the wrong way, sorry about that).

Comment: hey i'd love to help out, could you provide a screenshot of what it looks like on your end? and maybee what its supposed to look like:)?

Comment: Do i post it here or do i edit my question? and how do i post a screenshot in this site?

Comment: @VitorOliveira If you edit your question, there's a small image upload button to the left of the code snippet button. Are you applying any zoom on your browser or your OS settings?

Comment: @AStombaugh I uploaded the images, and as you can see i didn't apply any zoom onto the site. the site is just like that.